# Sleep mode and months of operation on small battery

Tags: power, sleep

In context of getting the MCU on Pro Mini and ATMega2560 (chip is ATmega328 and ATMega 2560) to **sleep and power down modes,** so as to run on **one set of battery for months**, appreciate idea and comment.

Initially, I looked at web postings and get the following general idea. Did I miss anything?

Is sleep mode done via ATMel factory library, Arduino-level user contributed library, or the Arduino IDE? Many web posting are along the line of getting it partially working but only at half expected current reduction, etc. That is, current do reduced, but, not enough.

Are there several such library?

How are they?

Which one is better support and more functions? (no need for easy to use, can do registers programming, when needed)

Many thanks in advance

Comment: "Seems like sleep mode is done via user contributed library, instead of core 'official' IDE." Wat. The API is in `avr/sleep.h`, which is even more "core" than the IDE.

Comment: Followed your lead, got http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__sleep.html and look like this is one of the several lib mentioned on web postings.

Comment: Yeah, why do it the simple way when you can add 5 files and 10kB of code :/

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams 5 files and 10kB of code?

Comment: @geometrikal: A slight exaggeration. But all the functionality required is built into AVR Libc already.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams In the jee lib I linked to there is a great function called `loseSomeTime` which falls to sleep for a set amount of time (using periodic watchdog interrupts to keep track). Also there is some code to turn off brown out detect which is not in the link from John Williams. For space saving one can simply copy the `Sleepy` class out into a separate file, it is only a few functions.

Comment: As an aside, the watchdog stinks for keeping track of time. If you need accuracy then use an asynchronous timer instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a read through the Jeelabs blog which documents the author's very successful attempt at making a very low power wireless sensor node that can run for months off coin cells.

http://jeelabs.org

There is also a library based on this project called Jeelib:

http://jeelabs.net/pub/docs/jeelib/

Jeelib contains a class called `Sleepy` that allows for easy sleeping.

Rocketscream did a thorough test of the current consumptions with the different modes here:

http://www.rocketscream.com/blog/2011/07/04/lightweight-low-power-arduino-library/

According to them, you can get the ATMega328P down to 1.7uA.

Unless you do something about the power supply on a normal Arduino board you won't be able to extend the battery life by much at all. See my answer here for some more details:

[Arduino powering from 9V battery](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/3688/arduino-powering-from-9v-battery/3689#3689)

Comment: +1 for resourceful pointers to rich sources of info. Edit the question on the power supply regulator chip. Some chip are uA rated while other are traditional higher power consumption.

Comment: You also should desolder the power-led on the boards. I prefer to skip the voltage regulator and get a battery pack that has the right voltage. E.g. three AA (3 x 1.5V = 4.5V). Most AVR chips have quite a range in acceptable voltages. Also running the chip without the crystal reduces the power use a bit I've heard. I never used crystals on my own homemade boards. Just read chapter 9 of the datasheet, especially 9.10!

Answer (score 1):

I could reproduce these power requirements - main thing is to get rid of the Arduino board and start with a Bareduino or sth similar. (find a detailed description [here](https://holadimake.wordpress.com/2015/01/02/building-a-cellular-tracker-part3-running-on-batteries-for-months/))

Comment: Another way is to use Pro Mini board. First, de-solder the power on LED light as it takes about 3mA. Battery feeds to the 5V pin without using the regulator. The LDO voltage regulator on my board takes up about 20 micro ampere in this un-used mode (likely, different brand/model of that chip has different current consumption). De-solder if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

- I have a page about saving power with the Atmega328P chips (similar techniques apply to other chips): [Power saving techniques for microprocessors](http://www.gammon.com.au/power)
- I made a [Temperature and humidity sensor - battery powered](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=12106) - this runs from 3 x AA batteries, and writes to an SD card. From memory it ran for 2 years before I needed to replace the batteries.
- Another project flashes an LED every second: [Simple project - torch-locator](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=12769). I made something similar a couple of years ago that is still running from the same button battery.

As a rule-of-thumb, you should be able to achieve 100 nA of current consumption, and still be "alive" and able to respond to external events, like button-presses (eg. a calculator or TV remote). To wake periodically (without an external event) takes more current, because you need the watch-dog timer to be active, but that can still be as low as 6 µA.