# Power saving of atmega 2560

Tags: power

Is arduino code Consume More power other than "Avr Studio" Code?

Please tell some key points for power saving.
Processor on $ off Methodology.

Comment: `Processor on $ off Methodology.` - not sure what you mean by that.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing about the Arduino code that would inherently consume more power than using a different compiler, so no, it doesn't. What the code does you can change in either development environment.

Read [Power saving techniques for microprocessors](http://www.gammon.com.au/power) for a considerable number of tips about saving power.

Also see related threads about this question such as [What are (or how do I use) the power saving options of the Arduino to extend battery life?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-are-or-how-do-i-use-the-power-saving-options-of-the-arduino-to-extend-bat)